# Argument is out of range on really simple array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've simplified the code I was working on as much as I could to try and get this to just print the value in the first cell. It keeps saying :

> Argument is out of Range" "mapArray.Star() (at
>   Assets/Scripts/mapArray.cs32)

Here is my current code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class mapArray : MonoBehaviour {

    public class gridCell
    {
        public int theX { get; set; }

        public gridCell(int xAx, int yAx, int TRVpen, int Ele, bool isOccupied)
        {
            this.theX = theX;
        }

    }

    public void Start()
    { 
       List<gridCell> cells = new List<gridCell>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 288; i++)
        {
            int theX = i;
        }
        int theXvalue = cells[0].theX;
        Debug.Log(theXvalue);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update () {

    }

 }
```

Comment: `List<gridCell> cells = new List<gridCell>();` creates a new array so there are not items in it. That's why you get this error when you do `int theXvalue = cells[0].theX;`

Comment: Is the for loop not putting items in the x value for 288 different elements in the array?

Comment: Loop is just assigning value of `i` to `theX` variable. It is no where setting value of `cells` array.

Comment: Ok inside the for loop i've added:

    cells[i] = new ?????(int theX = i);

what goes where the ???, is that even the right step?

Comment: before accessing the items of cells collection you have to add gridCell object to the collection cells

Comment: How can you access the items if they don't exist in the first place?

Comment: replace cells.add(new gridCell{ theX = i }) in the for loop instead of int theX = i

Comment: you seem to lack a basic understanding of c# programming. Perhaps do a few introductory tutorials and then try again.